# Twitter Bootstrap - Having multiple images in your background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-float, background-image

I've been coming back to this problem for the past two days and could use some help as I'm sure I am over-thinking. I am working on a simple three column page using the Twitter Bootstrap and would like to have these images (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sewsP.png) repeating vertically on the left and right sides of the window as the background. I've been trying to include them in the HTML as images and trying to manipulate them that way but can't get it to work without ruining the nice Bootstrap layout.

Any advice would be extremely appreciated,
Ryan

Ended up getting it by doing the following:

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: url(../images/background-right.png) right repeat-y, url(../images/background-right.png) left repeat-y, url(../images/background-middle.png) center repeat;

}

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with Bootstrap in a while.

Would setting three columns in the div with their own classes and setting a background image for each column work? Or did you try that already

```
.columnOne{
    background-image: "url";
}

.columnTwo{
    background-image: "url2";
}
.columnThree{
    background-image: "url3";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution won't play nice with my footer :( I'll keep trying though

Comment: This could just be hacking it together but try wrapping the main content. Seeing some code can help too, so i know what your structure looks like

Comment: take a look at that there may be helpful